# How to generate a random array as follows?

Tags: python, random

How to generate a random list as the following description?

> The random number range from 0 to 4.
> Assume the list named arr,
> arr[0]!=[1]; arr[2]!=[3]; arr[4]!=[5];arr[6]!=[7];........
>
> However, it's okay if arr[1]=arr[2];arr[3]=arr[4];arr[5]=arr[6]........
>
> A simple eg: arr = [1,2,2,0,3,2,1,3,0,1,1,0]

Comment: Your conditions are not clear. What does `arr[6] != [7]` even mean? Apparently you mean `arr[6] != arr[7]`. If so, why not say so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from random import sample
objects = (0, 1, 2, 3)

N = ... # some integer
result = []

for i in range(N):
    a, b = sample(objects, 2)
    result.append(a)
    result.append(b)

print(result)
```